# Rake task not adding CSV to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, rake-task

I'm trying to add rows of a CSV to records in a table and everything seems to be working fine besides the fact that nothing actually shows up.

Here is my Rake task:

```
namespace :csv do

  desc "Import CSV Data"
  task :c_up => :environment do

    require 'csv'

    csv_file_path = 'db/main.csv'

    CSV.foreach(csv_file_path, :headers => true) do |row|
      row = Entry.create!({
        :one => row[0],
        :two => row[1],
        :three => row[2],
        :four => row[3],
        :five =>row[4],
        :six => row[5],
        :seven => row[6],
        :eight => row[7],
        :nine => row[8],
        :ten => row[9]
      })
      row.save
      puts "Entry added!"

    end
  end
end
```

The headers in my CSV are named to match the attributes.

When I run the task I receive no errors and all of the "Entry added!" show up in the console.  I've tried it without the `row =` and `row.save` as I've seen lots of examples without those but it doesn't help.

After the rake finishes there aren't any records at all.  Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?  It seems like this is following most examples I've seen.

**Edit**  Thanks for all your answers and comments!  Obviously this is flawed all the way down to syntax, I'm going to try out your suggestions and I'll update this after.  Thanks again!

**Edit 2**  It turned out to be a syntax issue that you guys all pointed out, so +1 for everyone thanks!  The reason when I commented it still wasn't working was an unrelated problem which I wouldn't have figured out without @jvnill's comments.

Comment: it is weird that no record is created and you don't get any exception when you call `#create!`. are you sure your csv has some content?

Comment: contrary to the answers, even with the call to save and {}, it should still save as long as it passed validations.  a more helpful approach is to use `Entry.new` then `puts "Entry added!" if row.save` just to make sure that it is indeed trying to save the record and not just go through the loop

Comment: That's what I thought too, and I've tried it with new and I added the conditional for the `row.save` and `"Entry added!"` and it looks like everything is being saved fine and when I have Sublime Text open I can see the development.sqlite3-journal updating quickly when the new records are being added.  I guess it could be a problem elsewhere but I have no idea what could be messing with it.

Comment: Have you tried with my answer below? I have written it out of my head, I think it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
row = Entry.new(
        :one => row[0],
        :two => row[1],
        :three => row[2],
        :four => row[3],
        :five =>row[4],
        :six => row[5],
        :seven => row[6],
        :eight => row[7],
        :nine => row[8],
        :ten => row[9]
      )
      row.save!
```

Without **{ }** , and with **save!**

You could even try with this, to make it simpler:

```
Entry.create!(row.to_hash)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Entry.create!` does not require being assigned to row nor does it require a `row.save`.  Also know '{}'  Just do:

```
Entry.create!(
        :one => row[0],
        :two => row[1],
        :three => row[2],
        :four => row[3],
        :five =>row[4],
        :six => row[5],
        :seven => row[6],
        :eight => row[7],
        :nine => row[8],
        :ten => row[9]
      )
```

The create method will populate the row and save it as well.

Answer (score 0):

namespace :csv do

desc "Import CSV Data"
  task :c_up => :environment do

```
require 'csv'

csv_file_path = 'db/main.csv'

CSV.foreach(csv_file_path, :headers => true) do |row|
  Entry.create!({
    :one => row[0],
    :two => row[1],
    :three => row[2],
    :four => row[3],
    :five =>row[4],
    :six => row[5],
    :seven => row[6],
    :eight => row[7],
    :nine => row[8],
    :ten => row[9]
  })
end
```

end
end